# Print Multiple Sheet from User Input Using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I have a code which will take user input from a list box, which is the name of all the tabs I have in the workbook, selected name will be moved to another listbox, say Listbox2. This list box 2 items are being converted to an array to go to the print preview page. but the problem is, I'm doing it in a loop, so I can't print them in one go. If I select 5 tabs, I'm having to print 5 tabs separately. I want to print them together. I've tried putting the print preview command out of the loop, but then I get an error saying application not found or something similar. Here's the code below:

```
Private Sub Printout1_Click()
Dim Size As Integer

    Size = Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1
ReDim ListBoxContents(0 To Size) As String

    Dim i As Integer

  For i = 0 To Size
      ListBoxContents(i) = Me.ListBox2.List(i)

Next i

For i = 0 To Size
Sheets(ListBoxContents(i)).Visible = True
Sheets(ListBoxContents(i)).Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintPreview
    Sheets(ListBoxContents(i)).Visible = False
Next i


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy all the sheets in another sheet just for print , For exemple 
if he select sheet1 and sheet2

You can use a sheet called PRINTSHEET

and them Copy  the Sheet1.usedrange and Sheet2.usedrange to PrintSheet

after that u can just print the PrintSheet

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but that is not the ideal solution to my problem. Each of the sheet I'm trying to print contain charts and all charts need to be printed on separate sheets. The code I have now, prints them separately whereas I want them to print them all together, one file.